# Background appears black not cyan when using JFrame and Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, jframe

Hello I am making a program that creates a multi-flashing block on a cyan background in Java. I am using JFrames and Canvas but for some reason even if I specify for the color to be cyan it makes my background black. However the keylistener if blocks fill in the space with cyan if you move the box. Below is the code which I think is relevant to the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for reading this.(Note this is probably bad syntax and coding, but my theory is to make the code work before prettying it up.)

```
  GraphicsEnvironment ge =
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();

// Create off-screen drawing surface
BufferedImage bi = gc.createCompatibleImage( 640, 480 );

// Objects needed for rendering...


Graphics graphics = null;
Graphics2D g2d = null;

//Why isn't the background color cyan? (It's black)
Color background = Color.CYAN;
Random rand = new Random();

//The x and y positions are randomly generated as are the length and width
int x = rand.nextInt(640 / 2), y = rand.nextInt(640 / 2);
int w = rand.nextInt( 640/2 );
int h = rand.nextInt( 480/2 );





//To Do: Infinite loops suck, make a death variable
while( true ) {
    try {
    // clear back buffer...      

    g2d = bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g2d.fillRect( -1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 );

    // draw the rectangle...
      int r = rand.nextInt(256);
      int g = rand.nextInt(256);
      int b = rand.nextInt(256);
      g2d.setColor(new Color(r, g, b));
      g2d.fillRect( x, y, w, h );

    //Get the newly drawn rectangles and flip
    graphics = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(bi, x, y, canvas);
```

Comment: *"using JFrame and Canvas"* Don't mix Swing with AWT (pre Java 7).  Strange things will happen.  Use a `JComponent` or `JPanel` for custom painting.

Comment: Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136859/mouselistener-help-java/5137250#5137250) may be a useful starting point.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping and sorry for taking so long to respond. I had to scrap some of my old code to make it work, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to make the `JFrame` cyan colored with a canvas in it this is what I did:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test {
    static JFrame frame;
    static Canvas canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frame  = new JFrame();
        canvas = new Canvas();

        canvas.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that's not you want actually.

Comment: -1  How many times does it need to be repeated? **Don't mix Swing with AWT..** Also 1) Swing GUIs should be constructed and altered on the EDT.  2) Wherever you found that method of indenting lines, put it back there & use one of the standard ways.

Comment: What are you talking about, one of the standard ways? I know hundreds of people who indent and set up their brackets just like that. Just because it's not the way you indent doesn't mean it's not standard and yes I have seen programming books with this style of indentation.