# unable to apply graphics to if statement

Tags: java, graphics, if-statement

I'm writing a program that has a grid of squares that when you click on one, it changes color from black to red. I'm writing the if statement for the first square, and It's not letting me do anything with graphics. How do I 1) change the color to red, 2) draw a new square in the same place, and 3) why dosen't it like the `MouseHandler` class declaration?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class toggle extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,0,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,0,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,21,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,21,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,42,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,42,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,63,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,63,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,84,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,84,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,105,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,105,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,126,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,126,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,147,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,147,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,168,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,168,20,20);
        //
        g.fillRect(0,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(21,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(42,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(63,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(84,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(105,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(126,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(147,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(168,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(189,189,20,20);
        g.fillRect(190,189,20,20);
    }

    public toggle(){
        super();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("toggle");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setSize(226, 247);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        MouseHandler hand=new MouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(hand);

    }

    public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener{
        public void MousePressed (MouseEvent e){

            if(e.getX()<20&&e.getX()>0&&e.getY()<20&&e.getY()>0){


            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        new toggle();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also consider this alternative [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136859/mouselistener-help-java/5137250#5137250) using `JLabel` and a `MouseAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2) You need to keep state for each square, in a `boolean[][]` field, for instance, which would tell if each square in your grid is clicked or not. In your `paintComponent` method, check for the state of each square and call `g.setColor`, passing `Color.BLACK` or `Color.RED` as argument accordingly.

3) You need to implement all methods for the `MouseListener` interface:

```
public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener {
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
        // your logic here
    }

    public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) {
        // leave method empty, since you don't need to listen to this event
    }

    // Same as above for mouseClicked, mouseEntered, mouseExited
}
```

or extend the `MouseAdapter` class and override `mousePressed` if you don't care for the other `MouseListener` events:

```
public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e ) {
        // your logic here
    }

    // No need to override the other methods, since
    // MouseAdapter already has empty implementations for them
}
```

Also, the correct name for the method you're implementing is `mousePressed` (note the lowercase m).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped, but I still don't get how to solve the MouseListener issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the two options more clearly.

Comment: Okay, great, eveything works except now it thinks that that boolean "bos" is always true, even if I didn't click it. I'm writing the if statements for each square. This is for the first one:  if(e.getX()<20&&e.getX()>0&&e.getY()<20&&e.getY()>0){
                bos=true;                
            }                                                        What should I change for it to work?

Comment: Please edit your answer to reflect your code changes. Also, you have the wrong idea here. Rather than hardcoding each square's location in your code, you should use loops and basic math to calculate each square's position and to determine which square should change color based on the mouse position. Think about how your current code would change should you need to double the grid's dimensions, or change the square size.

Answer (score 1):

> 3) why dosen't it like the MouseHandler class declaration?

When you implement an interface you must provide an implementation for all the methods or declare the implementation `abstract`. In this case, you haven't implemented a single method - Java is case-sensitive and `MousePressed` is not the same as `mousePressed`, the method you do want to implement.

Also, you'll find that there are a few interfaces that have a lot more methods than you're interested in and you'll end up providing empty methods in order to satisfy the compiler. In such a case, you might look to see if there's an 'adapter' class you can extend. In this case, you'll find the [`MouseAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all the answers helped.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you don't need all of them g.fillRect(0,0,20,20);  You could use a loop to handle this since there is an occurring pattern for the first param in each line.