# Dynamically change JLabel icons based on x,y of mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am using NETBEANS and have several JLabels that need to display a specific icon/image based on a decision/boolean. I do not want to have to add a mouse listener for every JLabel and then copy and paste the code for each one. Rather I would prefer to use the x,y as the name of the JLabel and then set icon based on the x,y. I have no problems getting the x.y but cannot seem to figure out how to do something like this (xy.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hit)); here is my code.

```
/**
 * Mathematical coordinates of player1Fleet.
 * Used to realign ships from Ship Class
 * for use on game board.
 */
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Launch1();
}
public void FleetP1() {
    for (Ship s : player1Fleet) {
        int size = s.getSize();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            player1Ships.add((((s.getXCoordinate(i) + 1) * 45) + 90) + "" + (((s.getYCoordinate(i) + 1) * 45) + 180));

        }
    }
    // Verification of Math
    System.out.println(player1Ships);
}

/**
 * Determine Hit or Miss based on location of Cross-hairs
 * for player 1/West on game board.
 * @return 
 */
//public boolean setStrike1(){
public boolean Launch1() {
    w93.setIcon(null);
    player1Ships.clear();
    FleetP1();
    boolean strike1 = false;
    boolean Launch = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.player1Ships.size(); i++) {
        if (this.player1Ships.get(i).equals(LblCrossHairs.getX() + "" + LblCrossHairs.getY())) {
            strike1 = true;
            //break;
        }
        if (strike1) {
            strike1 = true;
            (LblCrossHairs.getX() + "" + LblCrossHairs.getY()).setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hit));
            //Launch = theAttack.Strike1(strike1);
            //w93.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hit));
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("MissleHit.au");
            AudioClip ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
            ac.play();
            System.out.println("HIT");
            break;
        } else {
            strike1 = false;
            (LblCrossHairs.getX() + "" + LblCrossHairs.getY()).setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hit));
            //w93.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Miss));
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("MissileMiss.au");
            AudioClip ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
            ac.play();
            System.out.println("MISS");
        }
    }
    TxtClick.setText(LblCrossHairs.getX() + "" + LblCrossHairs.getY() + ".setIcon");
    return strike1;
}
```

Thank you in advance for all your help. This has been driving me crazy for the last two days

Comment: What is your *question?*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to have to add a mouse listener for every JLabel and then copy and paste the code for each one.

You don't have to create a separate listener. You can share the same listener with every JLabel. The basic code is:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
    label.setIcon(...);
}
```

Comment: +1 Exactly; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136859/mouselistener-help-java/5137250#5137250).

Comment: Except I am hoping to use it in the Launch1 Method and when I do I get an error when I use it there.  Can not find symbol Symbol: Variable e  Location: Class game.GUI    If do the following; public boolean Launch1(label e) I get the same error only for label.

Comment: So pass the label to the Launch1(...) method as a parameter.