# Java - Creating a 2D tile map in a panel using Graphics2D Rectangles?

Tags: java, dictionary, graphics2d, tile

I'm trying to simulate a battle in a really basic program, but since this is my first time with a big program in Java I'm pretty much clueless on how to proceed. I was thinking I'd have a big 600-by-600 panel and use Graphics2D to just draw the terrain as 20x20 rectangles... Unfortunately even with several tutorials I have no idea what to do.

I have 10 different types of terrain to cycle through, and 5 different landscape profiles. Basically what I want the program to do is when I select a certain profile in a combobox, it paints the landscape and the two opposing sides in the battle (though I'm not quite there yet)

Honestly I haven't made very much progress in the program. Should I be using just Graphics2D and rectangles for something like this, or should I switch to OpenGL or something similar? Although with my current Java experience, I don't think I'd get very far with it without help. Anyways, here's what I have so far:

```
public class Map extends JPanel {
    int n = 1;
    int x; int y;
    int Area = 750;
    public Color City = new Color(214,217,223);
    public Color Desert = new Color(255,204,102);
    public Color DirtRoad = new Color(153,102,0);
    public Color Forest = new Color(0,102,0);
    public Color Hills = new Color(51,153,0);
    public Color Lake = new Color(0,153,153);
    public Color Mountains = new Color(102,102,255);
    public Color Ocean = new Color(0,0,153);
    public Color PavedRoad = new Color(51,51,0);
    public Color Plains = new Color(102,153,0);
    public Rectangle blocks[];
    public Map(){
        blocks = new Rectangle[750];
        if (n == 1) {
            setBackground(City);
            n = 2;
        } else if (n == 2) {
            setBackground(Desert);
            n = 3;
        } else if (n == 3) {
            setBackground(DirtRoad);
            n = 4;
        } else if (n == 4) {
            setBackground(Forest);
            n = 5;
        } else if (n == 5) {
            setBackground(Hills);
            n = 6;
        } else if (n == 6) {
            setBackground(Lake);
            n = 7;
        } else if (n == 7) {
            setBackground(Mountains);
            n = 8;
        } else if (n == 8) {
            setBackground(Ocean);
            n = 9;
        } else if (n == 9) {
            setBackground(PavedRoad);
            n = 10;
        } else if (n == 10) {
            setBackground(Plains);
            n = 1;
        } else {
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= Area; i++) {
            blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
        }
    }
```

I got this far with several Youtube tutorials, so my code is a bit erratic. All I have in the main form code is a checkBox firing event. (GUI is pre-designed in Netbeans editor.)

Comment: So..what's the question? Voting to close.

Comment: Should I be using Graphics2D or OpenGL to create my map, and how should I do so with either of those methods?

Comment: If those are images, don't bother with either and simply use `JLabel`s. If they are not (as your example indicates), then use `Graphics2D` by overriding the `paintComponent` of a `JComponent`.

Comment: @mre is right, e.g. [`ColorLabel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5137250/230513) or [`ImageLabelPanel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Comment: Trashgod, mre, thanks, I couldn't really figure out how I should start out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) I would strongly suggest you stick with learning Java 2d before OpenGL.
2) Ideally you would have some model view separation - you'd have one class representing the map  contents and another one to actually render it.

Here's some sample code that should get you a bit closer towards your goal.  Please try to read through and *understand* it, not just copy paste and hack away at it.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Map extends JPanel {

    public static final Color CITY = new Color(214,217,223);
    public static final Color DESERT = new Color(255,204,102);
    public static final Color DIRT_ROAD = new Color(153,102,0);
    public static final Color FOREST = new Color(0,102,0);
    public static final Color HILLS = new Color(51,153,0);
    public static final Color LAKE = new Color(0,153,153);
    public static final Color MOUNTAINS = new Color(102,102,255);
    public static final Color OCEAN = new Color(0,0,153);
    public static final Color PAVED_ROAD = new Color(51,51,0);
    public static final Color PLAINS = new Color(102,153,0);

    public static final Color[] TERRAIN = {
        CITY,
        DESERT,
        DIRT_ROAD,
        FOREST,
        HILLS,
        LAKE,
        MOUNTAINS,
        OCEAN,
        PAVED_ROAD,
        PLAINS
    };

    public static final int NUM_ROWS = 25;
    public static final int NUM_COLS = 30;

    public static final int PREFERRED_GRID_SIZE_PIXELS = 10;

    // In reality you will probably want a class here to represent a map tile,
    // which will include things like dimensions, color, properties in the
    // game world.  Keeping simple just to illustrate.
    private final Color[][] terrainGrid;

    public Map(){
        this.terrainGrid = new Color[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
        Random r = new Random();
        // Randomize the terrain
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
                int randomTerrainIndex = r.nextInt(TERRAIN.length);
                Color randomColor = TERRAIN[randomTerrainIndex];
                this.terrainGrid[i][j] = randomColor;
            }
        }
        int preferredWidth = NUM_COLS * PREFERRED_GRID_SIZE_PIXELS;
        int preferredHeight = NUM_ROWS * PREFERRED_GRID_SIZE_PIXELS;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredHeight));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Important to call super class method
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Clear the board
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        // Draw the grid
        int rectWidth = getWidth() / NUM_COLS;
        int rectHeight = getHeight() / NUM_ROWS;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
                // Upper left corner of this terrain rect
                int x = i * rectWidth;
                int y = j * rectHeight;
                Color terrainColor = terrainGrid[i][j];
                g.setColor(terrainColor);
                g.fillRect(x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
                Map map = new Map();
                frame.add(map);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - think I fixed it.  Please let me know if it still looks wrong.

Comment: Okay, this looks promising and I can pretty much understand what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: Question: I am not sure how the for loop works in paintComponent. Does it essentially individually draw over clear rect, rect by rect?

Comment: @fungusanthrax yes. I've cleared the rectangle (`g.clearRect`) and then I'm drawing filled rectangles on top of it (`g.fillRec`)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about learning java the wrong way to be honest. If that's what you're trying to do by learning from these tutorials.

*I personally don't have exprience in doing tile maps* but there are some things missing that I can see from reading your code.

Usually when I look at tile map code I see a 2D array of numbers, in your case it would be a 2D Array of numbers ranging from 1 - 10 placed in random indexes. From what I understand you're doing in the code you displayed is you're just assigning an image to a number and adding them to your blocks array.

Issue with that is, since there is no 2D array to actually visualize the map you are creating, all you're doing is creating an array is a bunch of Rectangles with backgrounds.

Another issue I can't make sense of is the fact you have your map area set to 720 indexes which is basically a field with, I don't know 27 images by 27 images will be your x and y value in those ints you created. leaving you with a JPanel divided up into the invisible tile map grid you are trying to create.

Based on what number is in the index of the 2D Array I was talking about earlier, the background will be filled in with the corresponding image.

**About the OpenGL or Graphics 2D issue:**
It doesn't matter what graphics library you use, the issue is how you code it. OpenGL is pretty advanced for a beginner to jump into (especially 2D, from my experience), it's a 3D library so even though 2D is possible, it's kinda hard. Learn some of the Java API before you go into any next step.

Hope I helped, or made sense O_o again I've never done tile maps so I'm responding to the code you posted.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I have this project due for a deadline and I think I bit off more than I could chew. Oh well, I hope it goes well!